# Repeat Last Command or Instruction in Xcode

Tags: xcode, command, repeat

While in Xcode, is there a way to repeat previously typed commands or instructions?
In other IDEs, I could use the [Up] or [Down] arrow to cycle through previously typed commands.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, but up/down works in the Xcode debugger console as well.

Comment: Suppose you type "print(a)" 
("a" being a variable.)
Later, in another part of the code, you want to type  "print(a)" again.
Instead of typing it again, or using Copy/Paste, it would be nice to hit the [Up] arrow or similar key to recall "print(a)".  Is this possible?

Comment: do you find any solution after one year? what I find is Xcode does not support http://chriswu.com/posts/xcode/vimtotd/